# Logstash refuse to see a postgres table

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash

so I created my logstash conf file, and spun up logstash, kibana, Postgres, and elasticsearch in one docker compose file, it connected seemlessly with my database however it says the table "products" don't exist.

`[2023-01-18T14:06:00,182][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ][main][6a13cd40fa144828caae9db4ed20b978765149c99cc59d5830fa4ccad80b4017] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>"Java::OrgPostgresqlUtil::PSQLException: ERROR: relation \"products\" does not exist\n  Position: 15"}`

**This is my conf**

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://elastic-postgres-1:5432/shopdb"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "****"
        jdbc_driver_library => "./postgresql-42.2.27.jre7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM products;"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://elasticsearch:9200"]
        index => "PostgreSQL"
    }
}
```

granted I did link my postgres to logstash with the conf BEFORE creating the table but I have tried re-starting the containers again. Again the error persists I tried putting in the wrong table to know if it's even updating the conf which it noticed so why isn't it seeing the table "products" which has been created and populated now?

Comment: May you need to refer the schema name like "SELECT * FROM schema_name.object_name"

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly to use the object schema name in your query for avoid this error not found the table.
like:

`SELECT * FROM schema_name.object_name`

Comment: You mean like: SELECT * FROM public.products; ?

Comment: yes, but you need to be sure what is the schema name of table.

Comment: use the \dt command from the PostgreSQL command prompt (psql)  to show tables in the  database.